# Google Stackdriver logging in App Engine (Python) using Redis queue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, redis, python-rq

I want to log using Stackdriver Logging to App Engine using Redis queue. So I'm using Redis Server, Redis Queue and Python logging to do this. Here's my code:

```
import logging
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
import time

class SomeClass():

def log_using_redis(self,text):
    log_text = logging.warn(text)
    f=open("stack_log.txt","a+")
    f.write(str(text))
    return "logged Successfully using redis"


def get(self):
    text = 'Hello, Logged Successfully!'+time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z(%z)')
    redis_conn = Redis()
    q = Queue(connection=redis_conn)
    job = q.enqueue(self.log_using_redis,text)
    print job.result
```

When I run RQ worker I'm getting some output on terminal but couldn't find where the logs are being stored.

If I try to log directly without using Redis, the logs are being stored at Global in the logging section of Google Cloud. The queue is working properly, to check I've been appending the text to a file.

It seems the logging isn't working. If it is being logged, where can I find my logs on Google Cloud?

Comment: I'm curious–are you using _[Google Cloud logger](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging/usage.html)_? Also I think the enqueued function should error because the worker wouldn't be able to import and run it with it being an instance method.

Comment: Try this: go to the GCP console, App Engine and services. Select the service in which you have deployed your application. In the right side click on tools and select "Logs". This will redirect the page to your app logs. Can you see them there?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Yes I'm using Google Cloud logger. The enqueue function is working, which I've referred from http://python-rq.org/ .

Comment: @RubénC. I've checked in all types of logs (like GCE, GAE, Global, etc.) but couldn't find logs anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that you are using Python client library, use `print()` function to obtain the desired results. I don’t know if you are testing the application locally or you have deployed it.

1. If you are testing the application locally: `print()` function
   output can be found in the cloud shell.
2. If you have deployed the application: go to the GCP console, App Engine and services. Select the service in which you have deployed
   your application. In the right side click on tools and select
   "Logs". This will redirect the page to your app logs.

A more precise logging can be defined using the [Stackdriver Logging for Python](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python). The warning level can be defined. This can help you manage your application or identify events of interest. Find an example code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/logging/cloud-client/handler.py).

You might find useful [Stackdriver Logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/agent-logs), an application based on fluentd that runs on your virtual machine (VM) instances. The Logging agent is pre-configured to send logs from VM instances to Stackdriver Logging. There are source and configuraiton files available for [redis](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluentd-catch-all-config/).

If you want a more general vision, [App Engine flexible environment logs official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/appengine-logs#appengine-vms) can help you to understand the different available logs.